# MS Access 2010 joining with sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to combine two tables but my results are showing incorrect data from one table.

One example is my first table has the following:

```
PositionCode AcctUnit BudgetFTE
JDFF           HRT      2
```

my second table does not contain any record for PositionCode=JDFF and AcctUnit=HRT however I get the following results with running the query below:

```
PositionCode AcctUnit BudgetFTE ActualFTE VarianceFTE           
JDFF           HRT       2          1         -1
```

sql code:

```
SELECT
    b.PositionCode,
    b.AcctUnit,
    e.POSITION,
    e.HM_ACCT_UNIT,
    b.FTE AS BudgetFTE,
    sum(e.FTE) AS ActualFTE,
    sum(e.FTE) - b.FTE AS VarianceFTE

FROM
    QryBudgetRollUp AS b 
    LEFT JOIN ActiveEmployees AS e ON
        ( b.PositionCode = e.POSITION ) AND
        ( e.HM_ACCT_UNIT = b.AcctUnit )

GROUP BY
    b.PositionCode,
    b.AcctUnit,
    e.POSITION,
    e.HM_ACCT_UNIT,
    b.FTE,
    e.FTE - b.FTE
```

sample data:

QryBudgetRollup

```
PositionCode    AcctUnit    FTE
    JDFF              HRT            2
    VIPP              HRT            1
   HROPSA             CMP            1
```

ActiveEmployees

```
C       E       CE     LAST_NAME        FIRST_NAME       EMP             PROCESS         HM_ACCT_UNIT       D        POSITION           D;P'        Date        SC    Expr1013    AP        PG    HC       FTE         PE
2     2343     22343    Doe              John            FT              CHRE              CMP              CMP       HROPSA         CMP;HROPSA   2/15/1999      H    $20.00  $40,000.00       4    1         1          $4,000.00 
2     2515     22515    Jetson           George          PT              CHRE              CMP              CMP       HROPSA         CMP;HROPSA   4/22/2014      H    $10.00  $20,000.00       2    1        0.5         $2,000.00 
4       18      418     Doe              Jane            FT              CSIS              HRT              HRT       VIPP           HRT;VIPP     11/1/2002      S    $40.00  $80,000.00       7    1         1          $8,000.00
```

Desired Query Results

```
PositionCode    AcctUnit    BudgetFTE   ActualFTE   VarianceFTE
JDFF            HRT         2           0           2
VIPP            HRT         1           1           0
HROPSA          CMP         1.5         2          -0.5
```

Comment: Would need to know more info on your table schema

Comment: Try removing your FTE fields from the GROUP BY since you're already summing them.  And since you're already JOINing the Position and AcctUnit, then there's no need to SELECT both of them - use the fields from "b"

Comment: geeFlo, I did those things and I'm still getting the same results

Comment: You're using LEFT JOIN, so you WANT to get data from the first table even if the second table doesn't have corresponding data. Otherwise you would use INNER JOIN.

Comment: What is wrong with query again? What did you expect? Your query returns *PositionCode* and *AcctNum* from *b* table.

Comment: @Parfait, I am expecting PositionCode = JDFF, AcctUnit = HRT, BudgetFTE=2, ActualFTE=0, and VarianceFTE=-2

Comment: Only PositionCodes that have a value on QryBudgetRollup and are null on ActiveEmployees are an issue, the others that are on both are correct.

Comment: Please post sample data of both tables so we can reproduce and fix.

Comment: @Parfait, still very new to Stack Overflow and I can't get the tables to show nicely, any suggestions?

Comment: @Parfait, I have updated my question with sample data